# JS Classes: avoiding manually assigning class variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a JS class and the constructor receives 100 parameters.  Is there a utility function that can assign those to the "this" context automatically, or do I need to write a function that will loop through those and attach those parameters to the "this" context of the class?  I'm guessing some "bind" related function in ES6 but if anybody knows, that'd be great.  I'm hoping to avoid something like:
   this.parameter1 = parameter1;
    this.parameter2 = parameter2;
I know that Angular has a shortcut for this but my context is outside of Angular 2+/Typescript.

Comment: *"receives 100 parameters"*. That is crazy! Use a single object instead and a default object and Object.assign to merge with defaults

Comment: 100 is an exaggeration, but suppose like 10 then.  still repetitive tasks often have helper functions.

Comment: Well that is what you asked. Even using 10 is too many. A single object makes it all much simpler

Comment: yes, but.. often times you work with legacy code that you didn't write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign all passed arguments to an object like below.

```js
const hello = class {
constructor() {
    this.myObj = {}
    Object.assign(this.myObj, arguments)
}
test() {
    console.log(this.myObj)
}
}

let test = new hello('hello', 'bye')

test.test()
```

Comment: Hard to configure defaults this way though

Comment: Try not to leak `arguments` objects outside the function. Put the `Object.assign` right in the constructor and drop the `.args` property.